# Merging Tagged PDF without ruining the tags

Tags: pdf, itext, itextpdf, merging-data

I am trying to merge two Tagged PDF's with the iTextPDF 5.4.4 version jar. After doing all the operations while closing the document on the line:  document.close();): . It throws the below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
PDF Creation Failed java.lang.NullPointerException
[B@1d5c1d5c
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.fixTaggedStructure(PdfCopy.java:878)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.flushTaggedObjects(PdfCopy.java:799)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(PdfDocument.java:836)
at com.itextpdf.text.Document.close(Document.java:416)
at PDFMerger.mergePDF(PDFMerger.java:189)
```

Please let me know what could be the cause of this issue.

Below is the code I use.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);

boolean setTagged=reader.isTagged() ; 

Document document = new Document();

PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("Merged.pdf"));

copy.setTagged();

document.open();

int n;
n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {

    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page,true));

}
copy.freeReader(reader);
document.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: According to the code (PdfCopy.fixTaggedStructure(PdfCopy.java:878)) iText seems to expect a **PG** entry somewhere but your source PDF does not contain it. Can you share it for analysis to check whether it is an issue of the document or of iText?

Comment: Thanks MKL. We would like to share the document to you for further analysis. Can you please let me know the email id to send it.

Comment: I've added an address to my stackoverflow profile description. I think, though, that other people also are interested, especially people developing iText. Unless the document shall not be publicly available, you might want to provide it via file sharing (e.g. dropbox or google) instead of mail.

Comment: Thanks MKL. I have sent you the document in mail. Can you please have a look on it.

Comment: @Comm can you send us the PDF you sent to mkl, so we can test the fix? I have added an e-mail address to my profile.

Comment: @rhens I have sent you the PDF to test the fix.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug in the current iText versions.

@Bruno maybe someone should look into this

`PdfCopy` has a method `fixTaggedStructure` which tries to fix the tagged structure which has been somewhat garbled by copying tagged pages. Up to the current iText 5.4.6-SNAPSHOT inclusively you find the following code

```
PdfDictionary dict = (PdfDictionary)iobj.object;
PdfIndirectReference pg = (PdfIndirectReference)dict.get(PdfName.PG);
//if pg is real page - do nothing, else set correct pg and remove first MCID if exists
if (!pageReferences.contains(pg) && !pg.equals(currPage)){
    dict.put(PdfName.PG, currPage);
    PdfArray kids = dict.getAsArray(PdfName.K);
    if (kids != null) {
        PdfObject firstKid = kids.getDirectObject(0);
        if (firstKid.isNumber()) kids.remove(0);
    }
}
```

for a **StructElem** tagged element `dict` from some array. This code implicitly assumes that there is an entry for the key `PdfName.PG` in that dictionary `dict` by doing `pg.equals(currPage)`. Unfortunately that entry is optional, e.g. the sample document provided by the OP contains such **StructElem** dictionaries referenced from some array without a **Pg** entry. This causes the NPE in question.

In this case it suffices to change the order in the `equals` call, i.e. instead of

```
if (!pageReferences.contains(pg) && !pg.equals(currPage)){
```

one should use

```
if (!pageReferences.contains(pg) && !currPage.equals(pg)){
```

or

```
if (pg != null && !pageReferences.contains(pg) && !pg.equals(currPage)){
```

depending on the actual program logic here.

@Bruno Please check which variant is semantically correct; I'm not really into this tagged structure stuff after all...

Comment: For some reason, I missed this question in November. I'm in New York now, and I had my second day of ISO committee meetings (we talked about PDF for more than 9 hours in a row today). I have two more days to go. I'll create a ticket in our paid ticketing system referring to this question. As soon as our support engineers have fixed this, Raf Hens or myself will post a message here.

Comment: @Comm, the fix was added to our development version.  It will be included in the next release.  You can already build from our SVN repo on Sourceforge, if you want.

Comment: @rhens, Thanks. Can you please let us know when is the next release?

Comment: @Comm, I expect it to be around end of January, mid February.

Comment: @rhens, Thank you. We built 5.4.6 jar in the svn repo and its working fine now. Please let us know when it is released so that we can go ahead and use that.

Comment: @rhens, We are using PdfWriter from itextpdf 5.5.0 jar to merge the pdfs in tagged format. When we are doing this we can see the size of pdf is increasing very much. Below is the snippet code we use for merging. Is there any setup available to reduce the size.?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 Document document = new Document();
 PdfWriter  writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOS);
 writer.setTagged();
 document.open();
 PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
 int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
 for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
 document.newPage();
 PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
 cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0,true);
 }
 byteArrayOS.flush();
 document.close();
 byteArrayOS.close();

Answer (score 0):

The Code was written in C#

```
  public static byte[] mergeTest(byte[] pdf) {
        PdfReader reader = null;
        Document doc = null;
        PdfCopy copy = null;
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] output = null;

        try {
            reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            doc = new Document();

            copy = new PdfCopy(doc, stream);
            bool tagged = reader.IsTagged();

            if (tagged)
                copy.SetTagged();


            doc.Open();

            for (int x = 1; x <= reader.NumberOfPages; x++) {
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, x, tagged));
            }

            copy.FreeReader(reader);
            doc.Close();
            copy.Close();

            output = stream.ToArray();

            stream.Flush();
            stream.Dispose();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.Close();
            } catch (Exception) { }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Capiono, Thanks for your comments. Even after setting this tag based on the original document, we are facing the same issue.
We would like to know what the itextpdf jar is checking at this line at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.fixTaggedStructure(PdfCopy.java:878)
so we can find whether the original tagged pdf is having that proper structure.

Comment: Okay, I'm seeing this error now. Started after I upgraded to the latest version 5.4.4.0. I spoke to Itext, they know about it and working on a fix. They we have a new release at the end of the month.

Comment: Thanks Capiono. I tested even using 5.4.0 and 5.4.2 versions and got the same error. Can you please let us know whether this error is present in all the itextpdf versions handling Tagged pdfs or only the 5.4.4 version has this issue.

Comment: We are still facing the issue. Can anyone help us with the info.

Comment: The new library/jar is out, that should contain the fix for this issue.

Comment: Thanks Capiono. But the new version jar also gives the same exceptions. The PDFs have no warnings in Acrobat preflight. Please let us know if there are anything else we need to check.

Comment: Thanks Capiono. But we are having issues with above code too.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the PDF?

Comment: I guess so as we don't have any warnings in Acrobat preflight.